# Undefined is not an object (evaluating 'table.tBodies[0].rows') parsing an html table using .js

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, mysql

I have a table that is filled with data from the user, when the user has added all the values (the number of entries is variable), I have a button where it parses the data from the table (the idea is to store it on MySQL latter). But when testing it it returns the error:

> Undefined is not an object (evaluating 'table.tBodies[0].rows')

The button to execute this function only appears when there is data on the table so the problem is not that the table is empty.

Relevant code:

```html
       <div class="container">
            <div class="tab tab-1">
                <table id="table" border="1">
                    <tr>        
                        <th>First Name</th>
                        <th>Last Name</th>
                        <th>Age</th>
                        <th>Delete</th>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div>
            <div class="tab tab-2">
                First Name :<input type="text" name="fname" id="fname">
                Last Name :<input type="text" name="lname" id="lname">
                Age :<input type="number" name="age" id="age">
                
                <button onclick="addHtmlTableRow();">Add</button>
                <br>
            <button onclick="parseTableData();" id="togglee" style="visibility:hidden;">Add dataBase</button>
               
            </div>
        </div>
        
        <script>
               let table = document.getElementById("table");
            // check the empty input
            function checkEmptyInput()
            {
                var isEmpty = false,
                    fname = document.getElementById("fname").value,
                    lname = document.getElementById("lname").value,
                    age = document.getElementById("age").value;
            
                if(fname === ""){
                    alert("First Name Connot Be Empty");
                    isEmpty = true;
                }
                else if(lname === ""){
                    alert("Last Name Connot Be Empty");
                    isEmpty = true;
                }
                else if(age === ""){
                    alert("Age Connot Be Empty");
                    isEmpty = true;
                }
                return isEmpty;
            }
            
            // add Row
            function addHtmlTableRow()
            {
                if(!checkEmptyInput()){
                var newRow = table.insertRow(table.length),
                    cell1 = newRow.insertCell(0),
                    cell2 = newRow.insertCell(1),
                    cell3 = newRow.insertCell(2),
                    cell4 = newRow.insertCell(3),
                    fname = document.getElementById("fname").value,
                    lname = document.getElementById("lname").value,
                    age = document.getElementById("age").value,
                    edit = "Edit"
            
                cell1.innerHTML = fname;
                cell2.innerHTML = lname;
                cell3.innerHTML = age;
                cell4.innerHTML = edit;
                table = document.getElementById('table')
                deleteRow(table)
                
                document.getElementById('togglee').style.visibility = 'visible';
            }
            }
        function deleteRow(table){
            for(let i = 0; i < table.rows.length; i++)
        {
           if(table.rows[i].cells[3].innerText == 'Edit'){
            table.rows[i].cells[3].onclick = function() 
            {
                var c = confirm("do you want to delete this row");
                if(c === true)
                {
                    index = this.parentElement.rowIndex;
                    table.deleteRow(index);
                }
                
            };
           }
            
        }
        }
            
        </script>
        
         <script src="parseTable.js"></script>
            <script>
            
            function parseTableData() {
              var table1 = document.querySelector('#table');
              var output1 = document.querySelector("pre");
              var data1 = parseTable(table1);
              console.table(data1);

            }
            </script>
```

**The JS File:**

```js
/**
 * @license
 *
 * The MIT License (MIT)
 *
 * Copyright (c) 2014 Nick Williams
 *
 *
 * @param  {Array<String>} headings the values of the table's <thead>
 * @return {(row: HTMLTableRowElement) => Object} a function that takes a table row and spits out an object
 */
function mapRow(headings) {
  return function mapRowToObject({ cells }) {
    return [...cells].reduce(function(result, cell, i) {
      const input = cell.querySelector("input,select");
      var value;

      if (input) {
        value = input.type === "checkbox" ? input.checked : input.value;
      } else {
        value = cell.innerText;
      }

      return Object.assign(result, { [headings[i]]: value });
    }, {});
  };
}

/**
 * given a table, generate an array of objects.
 * each object corresponds to a row in the table.
 * each object's key/value pairs correspond to a column's heading and the row's value for that column
 *
 * @param  {HTMLTableElement} table the table to convert
 * @return {Array<Object>}       array of objects representing each row in the table
 */
function parseTable(table) {
  var headings = [...table.tHead.rows[0].cells].map(
    heading => heading.innerText
  );

  return [...table.tBodies[0].rows].map(mapRow(headings));
}
```

Offtopic: Is there an easy way to convert the dynamic table into an object to store into MySQL?

Thanks

Comment: try adding <tbody></tbody> to your table.

Comment: Solved, thanks a lot!